# Is there a way to check if an infowindow is opened for a specific marker in google maps v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I currently have a bunch of markers that I store in an array to keep track of them.  When I click on a specific link it opens up that marker's infowindow.  Is there a way to do a check in the click listener to see if the infowindow I want opened is the currently opened one?  If so, don't close and reopen the infowindow?

Current javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var infowindow = null;
    var stored_markers = new Array();

    function initialize() 
    {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 1,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        setMarkers(map, items);
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "holding..."
        });
    }

    var items = [
        ['title 1 to display on hover', latitude 1, longitude 1, z-index 1, 'infowindow 1 content'],
        ['title 2 to display on hover', latitude 2, longitude 2, z-index 2, 'infowindow 2 content'],
        ['title 3 to display on hover', latitude 3, longitude 3, z-index 3, 'infowindow 3 content']
    ];

    function setMarkers(map, markers) 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
        {
            var sites = markers[i];
            var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: siteLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: sites[0],
                zIndex: sites[3],
                html: sites[4]
            });
            stored_markers.push(marker);
            //initial content string
            var contentString = "Some content";

            //attach infowindow on click
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () 
            {
                infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });

        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: `specific link` what does this signify? Do you have links outside the map which open up the infowindow on click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wrap the infowindow-content into a element with an id which gives you the relation to the marker:

```
html: '<div id="infowin'+stored_markers.length+'">'+sites[4]+'</div>'
```

now you can check from anywhere if a specific infowindow is open, e.g. for the 3rd marker(note that the index starts with 0)

```
try{if(typeof(document.getElementById('infowin2').nodeType))
    {alert('infowindow for marker3 is open');}}
catch(e){alert('infowindow for marker3 is not open');}
```

Demo: [**http://fiddle.jshell.net/doktormolle/Ye3Wh/**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/doktormolle/Ye3Wh/)

Answer (score 0):

Marker is able to save and get your own properties, because Marker class extends MVCObject.
So I recommend like this code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: siteLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: sites[0],
                zIndex: sites[3],
                html: sites[4],
                markerIdx : "idx" + i  //Add your property
            });
```

And the listener is like this.

```
//attach infowindow on click
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () 
{
    alert(this.get("markerIdx"));      //Get the property of the marker which was clicked.
    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With API v3, you only need this to check if an infowindow is open:
`if (infoWindow.getMap())`

If you want to link a marker  with a specific infoWindow, you might want to create an array where the index of each infoWindow matches the index of its marker. Then with `infoWindow[marker_index]` you can easily check what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Following on @wf9a5m75 suggestion i added the infoWindow as a property to the marker

```
marker.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: 'Some info window content'
});
```

i also added a listener to the click event

```
marker.addListener('click', () => markerClickHandler(marker));
```

On this handler i check for opened info windows like this

```
function markerClickHandler(marker) {
 if (mapHasOpenInfo()) {
   // some code
 }  
}
```

And this is the method to find any open marker, all you need is the array with all markers for a map object.

```
function mapHasopenInfo(markers) {
  return markers.find(marker => marker.isOpen === true);
}
```